# Subscript affects line spacing in Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

I've seen the following behaviour in Impress and Draw, and also in Writer *when using text frames*, but not in normal text:

Type a few lines in a text frame, then create a subscript in the text → the line spacing below the subscript is changed. This does not happen for superscripts.

[image: The same paragraph, side by side, in a text frame each, inside LibreOffice Draw. The left version has a subscript in one line, and the following line spacing is increased over the right version]

I've observed this in multiple versions of LO, for some time now, and on Linux and Windows. (the example above was created on Kubuntu 20.04, with LO 6.4.7.2).

##### Some observations

I've tried to change line spacings, or any other potentially-related settings in `format → paragraph`, but it seems to have no effect. I also went through a series of fonts, including Arial, Liberation and Libertine, and they all show the same behaviour. Customizing the subscript position also does not help, unless I significantly reduce the `raise/lower by`setting, to about 10%.

Interestingly, superscripts don't affect line spacing either in regular text or inside of frames, but I can still make it happen by increasing the `raise/lower by` value far enough.

More interestingly, the reason why the problem does not occur outside of text frames is that subscripts in "regular" Writer text are not lowered so much:

[image: The same text, in Writer, including subscripts -- the subscripted characters are not lowered as much as in the previous examples, and don't affect line spacing]

I can replicate this in Draw, by manually adjusting the `lower by` value, but that is not solving my problem, because I'd *hate* having to enter a context menu and manually adjusting the character position for every single subscript ...

##### The question, thus:

Is there a better way to prevent subscripts from affecting line spacing, in all my text frames? I haven't found a global setting that affects the position of all subscripts, and the "auto" setting obviously.

Related to this: Why is the subscript position different between text frames and regular text, in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not precisely an answer, but I needed to include images and links... Could this be related to the *version* of LibreOffice, i.e., a bug now fixed? For example, there was a [similar bug fixed ~8 years ago](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=95272), and a more recent bug [specifically about line spacing in a text box](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=131149), which appears to be fixed in the version I'm now using.

When I tried to reproduce the issue in version 7.5.1.2 (X86_64), there was no difference (visible to me) in line spacing between text in a box and that outside:

[image: Sub/Superscripts in LibreOffice Text Box]

Different fonts were tried, both in and out of the text box, including Garamond, Liberation Serif, Calibri and even fixed-width Inconsolata, with the same uniform spacing.

**However,** when I select text, whether in the textbox or outside it, and in the menu, select *Format > Spacing > Decrease Paragraph Spacing*, superscripts and subscripts *no longer extend above and below the line*. Subscripts don't even descend to the level of the descender in *g*, for example.

Please let me know if updating LibreOffice helps.

To update to newer versions than Ubuntu maintains, I [added LibreOffice as PPA](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/libreoffice):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

There is some attendant risk, as the newest versions have not been vetted as thoroughly as older "still" versions.

Comment: For more careful people: The "still" versions are available from: `ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-still`. That moved me from LO 6.4 to 7.4 (yay!)

Comment: Now that I updated and am looking through the release notes: It was fixed in version 7.0: https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/7.0#Impress_&_Draw -- the release notes also have links to the bug reports.

Comment: @Zak, glad it now works. It's unfortunate that Ubuntu does not often update apps in older versions of the OS; only installs them in new releases. For that reason, I've added Mozilla as PPA for Thunderbird and Firefox, as well as LiberOffice PPA,.